# java user input for Array - split by space

Tags: java, arrays

All,

Below code is working fine with the ArrayList. could you please help me on how to get user input for name gender and amountSpent (array size [4]), then split it by spaces so that it will have String, String and double.

Also, How to display the result of only the customer who has higher amount Spent then the other Customers.

thank you in advance!

Regards,

Viku

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public  class Customer  implements Comparable <Customer>{

    public String name,gender;
    public double amountSpent;



        public Customer(String name, String gender, double amountSpent) {

            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.amountSpent = amountSpent;
    }


        public String getCustomername() {

            return name;
    }

        public void setCoustomername(String name) {

            this.name = name;
    }

        public String getgender() {

            return gender;
    }

        public void setGender(String gender) {

            this.gender = gender;
    }

        public double getamountSpent() {

            return  amountSpent;
    }

        public void setamountSpent(double amountSpent) {

            this.amountSpent = amountSpent;
    }
```

```
 public static Comparator <Customer> CustomerNameComparator  = new Comparator<Customer>() {


            public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {


                String custName1 = c1.getCustomername().toUpperCase();
                String custName2 = c2.getCustomername().toUpperCase();

                //ascending order
                    //return custName1.compareTo(custName2);

                        //descending order
                            return custName2.compareTo(custName1);
            }
        };
```

```
        public static Comparator <Customer> CustomerAmountSpentComparator  = new Comparator<Customer>() {


            public int compare(Customer aS1, Customer aS2) {


                int custamtspent1 = (int) aS1.getamountSpent();
                int custamtSpent2 = (int) aS2.getamountSpent();

                //ascending order sort
                 // return custamtspent1 - custamtSpent2;

                        //descending order sort
                            return custamtSpent2 - custamtspent1;
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Customer o) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return " Customer Name : " + name + ",  Gender : " + gender + ", Amount Spent : " + amountSpent + "";
        }

}
```

and Main Program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainProg {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String nL = System.lineSeparator();

        try {

        ArrayList<Customer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Customer> ();

        arraylist.add(new Customer ("Louis","Male", 4567.76));
        arraylist.add(new Customer ("Daniela","Female", 7653.67));
        arraylist.add(new Customer ("Jenny","Female", 3476.98));
        arraylist.add(new Customer ("Arijit","Male", 9876.44));


        System.out.println("Customer Name Decending Sort: " + nL);
        Collections.sort(arraylist, Customer.CustomerNameComparator);

            for (Customer str: arraylist) {

                System.out.println(str);

            }

            System.out.println(nL + "Custmer Amount Spent [Hight to Low]  Sorting: " + nL);

                Collections.sort(arraylist, Customer.CustomerAmountSpentComparator);

                for (Customer str: arraylist){
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

            System.out.println(nL + "Highest Amount Spent Custmer Detail: " + nL);



        }


        catch (Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error: " + e);

        }

        finally {

            System.out.println(nL + "Report Completed!");

        }



        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: Hi Stewart, i have two questions..... 1) need to take user input instead initializing values in Array List.  I have tried Scanner however when user input the values i.e. name gender amountSpent ... i am not sure how to separate them and store as String, String and double.   2) the array is sorted with higher to low amount spent ... but i don't know how to display the result of only that Customer who has spend higher than other Customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION 1 (suggested):**

If the user is to input the data, why do you need to split it up? Just do as follows:

```
System.out.println("Name:");
name = scn.nextLine();
System.out.println("Gender:");
gender = scn.nextLine():
System.out.println("Amt:");
amt = scn.nextDouble();

Customer c1 = new Customer (name,gender, amt);
```

---

**OPTION 2:**

Alternatively, if you want user to input everything in one single line (separated by spaces), just do this:

```
System.out.println("Input name, gender, amt:");
name = scn.next();
gender = scn.next():
amt = scn.next();

Customer c1 = new Customer (name,gender, amt);
```

**PROGRAM OUTPUT:** Input name, gender, amt: *John Male 33.50*

---

**OPTION 3 (requested  by you):**

Lastly if you still insist of doing a split by space, and you want to accept the user input in **one** string separated by spaces:

```
System.out.println("Input name, gender, amt:");
input = scn.nextLine();
String[] token = input.split(" ");
String name = token[0];
String gender = token[1];
double amt = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);

Customer c1 = new Customer (name,gender, amt);
```

**PROGRAM OUTPUT:** Input name, gender, amt: *John Male 33.50*

Comment: This is what i was looking for split method. it is perfect. thank you so much. really appreciated.  Regards,  Viku

Comment: @Viku If my answer was helpful to you, maybe you can consider accepting my answer by clicking on the tick beside my answer ;)

Comment: Hello user3437460 - done. Sorry new to this forum. i am learning. :)  Regards, viku

Comment: @viku No problem, I was once a new user too ;)

Comment: @Viku I saw that you accepted my answer, and did you removed it?

Comment: No - i didn't. However, as i am new, didn't know that i can accept only one answer. i accepted Julian's answer too (for my second question). Now all fixed....lot to learn.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question (if I have understood right), you want to take a user input as string:

> Dave Male 123.45

and then parse this into two Strings and a double. Scanner as you mentioned is a good way to start, then try

> String[] parts = input.split(" ");
>
> double value = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);

This will split the input into a String array of size 3 and convert the third element to a double object, that will allow you to create Customers.

For your second question, you can use a simple approach by iterating over all Customers in the ArrayList, and store the current customer with the highest amount. Replacing the customer if you find a bigger spender.

Answer (score 0):

Viku, try moving

> arraylist.add(new Customer(name,gender,amountSpent));

to within the

```
do{
  ...
  arraylist.add(new Customer(name,gender,amountSpent));
} while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
```

As the code is now, the arrayList.add is only executed after the loop -> only last entry.

Comment: Julian - it is working like a treat. I have used  collections.max(arraylist)  to print the highest amount spent Cusotmer details... it is working fine as well. Thank you so much for your help.  Regards, Viku